# The value of hash_hmac sha256 has different value using different post procedures

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, hmacsha256

I made two ways of requesting a POST. Method 1 is submitting the form to the server. Method 2 is using Jquery $.post.

```
<!--METHOD 1-->
<form method="POST" action="postmanTest.php" id="#myform">

  <input type="hidden" id ="bodyv" name="bodyv" value="aaab">

  <input type="hidden" id ="time" name="time">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Now" id="btn2" name="submit" onclick="stringify()">
   
</form>

<button id = "btn3">Set TIme</button>


<script>

  //---METHOD 2---
  $("#btn2").click(function(){

    stringify();
    
    $bodyv=$("#bodyv").val();


    
    $.post("postmanTest.php",
      {bodyv:$bodyv},
      function(data,status){
        alert(data);
      }
    )

  })

  //---SET TIME---
  $("#btn3").click(function(){

    document.getElementsByName('time')[0].value = new Date().getTime();

  })
  
</script>
```

The stringify function

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function stringify(){



  let time = document.getElementsByName('time')[0].value;

  let body = {
      "data": {
        // "scheduleAt": "2022-04-01T14:30:00.00Z", // optional
          "serviceType": "MOTORCYCLE",
          //"specialRequests": ["TOLL_FEE_10"], // optional
          "specialRequests": ["CASH_ON_DELIVERY"], // optional
          "language": "en_PH",
          "stops": [
            {
                "coordinates": {
                      "lat": "0",
                      "lng": "0"
                  },
                  "address": "Innocentre, 72 Tat Chee Ave, Kowloon Tong"
            },
            {
                "coordinates": {
                      "lat": "0",
                      "lng": "0"
                  },
                  "address": "Canton Rd, Tsim Sha Tsui"
            }
          ],
          "isRouteOptimized": false, // optional only for quotations
          "item":{
                "quantity":"12",
                "weight":"LESS_THAN_3_KG",
                "categories":[
                  "FOOD_DELIVERY",
                  "OFFICE_ITEM"
                ],
                "handlingInstructions":[
                  "KEEP_UPRIGHT"
                ]
        },
      }
  };

  body = JSON.stringify(body);

  document.getElementsByName('bodyv')[0].value = `${time.toString()}\r\nPOST\r\n/v3/quotations\r\n\r\n${body}`;


  
}
```

The server side PHP code accepts the variables and applies hash_hmac sha256 to the bodyv variable

```
 <?php


 $bodyVar = $_POST['bodyv'];



 $secret = "mysecretkey";

 $sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $bodyVar, $secret);


 echo $sig;
```

Method 1 and method 2 produce different values for $sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $bodyVar, $secret). Why is this happening? Method 1 is the correct hash value.

Comment: What does **stringify** do? And what is the error for method 2?

Comment: I've edited the main question to show what stringify does.

Comment: Please always include error messages.

Comment: The PHP code sends a post request to an API (Lalamove API). Method 1 succeeds in getting a correct result. Method 2 returns ERR_AUTHENTICATE HMAC signature doesn't match the provided payload.

Comment: When you echo **$bodyVar** in php for both instances the values are the same?

Comment: yes. Method 1: a7eb0c4e862623ecbd81cc62f060f6f3892b1b84cf7b028eab27d4896df7eff0. 
 Method 2: a0aa5ac70bf64ffdc2eb4063c7bcd2f4226798b8558844d5e38be5968e3d1907

Comment: I have edited the original question. I have cleaned the code and pasted the entire working code here. I'm still getting different values at the moment.

Comment: If you are using time, it will be different as the time is always different.

Comment: The function $("#btn3").click(function() should set the time variable once only. Any other subsequent function call should not change the time variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching, I saw you are using `\r\n` to set `$bodyv` data. And when you get that data with `$bodyv = $("#bodyv").val()` the `\r` is stripped. That´s because `val()` strips carriage return chars as explained [here](https://api.jquery.com/val/). You could change to  $bodyv = $("#bodyv")[0].value;` and it will work as expected

*Edited to match the correct answer*

Comment: I tried to add a hidden input with id = time. I create a separate button to set the hidden input = current time (document.getElementsByName('time')[0].value = new Date().getTime();)   .  This should set the time variable so that it will be the same on Method1 and Method 2. I'm still getting different hash values. In stringify is changed so that it will have same value (let time = document.getElementsByName('time')[0].value;)

Comment: After researching, I saw you are using `\r\n` to set `$bodyv` data. And when you get that data with `$bodyv = $("#bodyv").val()` the `\r` is stripped. That´s because val() strips carriage return chars as explained [here](https://api.jquery.com/val/). You could change to `$bodyv = $("#bodyv")[0].value;` and it will work as expected.

Comment: How do I make this the correct answer? Thanks a lot, that really amazing!